# Choose theme depending on the USER_AGENT

Tags: 6

How do I use the mobile theme if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is mobile, and use the desktop theme if it is desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [browsecap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) module to detect what browser users use and [switchtheme](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme) module to switch to correct theme depending on the browser they use.

Answer (score 3):

The [mobile tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) module also integrates with the [browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) module as well as the [wufrl](http://drupal.org/project/wurfl) module, though I recommend starting with browscap instead of wufrl. Wufrl is more complicated to set up and also not open source anymore.

Mobile tools gives you some handy options like choosing different themes for iPhone vs. Android vs Nokia, Panels module integration, special (optional) permissions for mobile users, and other options.  You can also force mobile users to use the mobile theme or let them choose between mobile and desktop a la the switchtheme module.